# why this variable is not optimized out

Tags: c, linux

I have a simple snippet where compiler optimized out the variable "done"

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool done = false;

void *func(void *args)
{
    done = true;

    return NULL;
}

main()
{
    pthread_t p1;
    
    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, func, NULL);
    printf("waiting\n");
    
    while(!done)
    {}
    printf("moving on...\n");
}
```

Here, in absence of volatile keyword, variable "done" is optimized away and run into infinite loop.

I am compiling using:

gcc -O2 volatile.c -lpthread

But when I use simple func() version:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool done = false;

void func()
{
        done = true;

}

main()
{
        func();
        printf("waiting\n");

        while(!done)
        {}
        printf("moving on...\n");
}
```

But here the variable "done" is not optimized out, what the difference between the two ?

Compiler in second case guessed out the "done" is going to change some how but not in case of Pthread?

My GCC version is:

gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: What do you mean by "optimized"?  You haven't provided any of the command-line options you've used.

Comment: `variable "done" is optimized away ` How do you know it's "optimized away"? It's just `true`. It's `bool done = true;`, did you mean to `bool done = false;`?

Comment: @KamilCuk, yeah I just updated the snippet.

Comment: Then, now, it's not an endless loop..

Comment: How are you checking the variable is optimized away? Do you just mean the loop does (not) terminate?

Comment: I think, I should have said, while(!done) is optimized to while(true) , instead of saying varibale is optimized or something.

Comment: By the way, for portable C, `volatile` is not enough to prevent a data race and undefined behavior.  You must make `done` an `atomic` type (which will also prevent the unwanted optimization)

Answer (score 2):

The variable `done` is not optimized out in either case.  What is optimized out (in both cases) is the *read* of `done` in the while loop.  That read is hoisted out of the loop and happens once before the loop; the loop then runs 0 times or infinitely depending on the value of `done` read before the loop.  It effectively becomes

```
    if (!done)
        while (true) {}
    else
        while (false) {}
```

which is then further simplified to just

```
    if (!done) while (true) {}
```

Comment: Then, of course, in the second program, we definitely have `done == true` before the loop begins (because `func()` has returned), so the infinite loop is not executed and everything is fine.  In the second case, there is a data race, so `done` might be either true or false when it's read before the loop, and so we might get an infinite loop or no loop at all.  (Or nasal demons, since after all a data race is UB.)

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. includes the missing header file: 'stdio.h' for 'printf()' and 'fprintf()'
2. properly exits the thread function
3. properly causes the 'main' thread to wait for the sub thread
   to avoid 'burning all the available CPU cycles'
4. properly checks the status of the call to 'pthread_create()' -- this function does not set 'errno'
5. properly handles the 'args' parameter to avoid a compiler warning
6. eliminates the 'useless' variable 'done'
7. uses a valid signature for 'main()'
8. incorporates appropriate horizontal spacing for readability
9. eliminates unneeded header 'stdbool.h'

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>  // printf(), fprintf()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit() and EXIT_FAILURE

//bool done = false;

void *func( void *args )
{
    (void)args;   // eliminate warning about unused argument
    //done = true;

    //return NULL;
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}

int main( void )   //use valid signature for 'main()'
{
    pthread_t p1;
    
    if( pthread_create( &p1, NULL, func, NULL ) != 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "call to pthread_create() failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf( "waiting\n" );
    pthread_join( p1, NULL );  // wait for sub thread to exit
    
    //while(!done)
    //{}
    printf( "moving on...\n" );
}
```